# What is the opposite of patronising?

Tags: meaning, synonyms, literature

Something to the sense of - guininely treat in a way that is apparently kind or helpful, and overly praise and make the person feel superior. Even though there is nothing much much to praise about.

All this with the general sense of feeling oneself inferior to the person - can be mentally, spiritually or physically.

Comment: **Encouraging** might be the word you want. Could you give a sentence in which you would use the word?

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for **deference**?

Comment: **Deference**: [Cambridge] (https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/power), "respect shown for another person, esp. because of that person's experience, knowledge, age, or power".

Comment: I am looking for a word where the respect is undeserving.

Comment: Maybe **obsequious**: obedient or attentive to an excessive or servile degree.

Comment: Sure sounds like you're talking about "patronizing".